# Erro Access denied for user em conexao

Tags: php, mysqli

Alguem sabe me dizer por que estou encontrando este erro ?

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'clienteaces'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Empresa Hard_php\to_db.php on line 24
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\Empresa Hard_php\to_db.php on line 26

Código:

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$conta = 'clienteaces';
$pass = 'abcdef123456';
$db = 'hard'; 



$conexao = mysqli_connect($ip,$conta,$pass,$db);
if(!$conexao){
   die("Não Conectado : ". mysqli_error($conexao)); 
   echo "O formulario não foi preenchido tente novamente mais tarde...";    
}
else{
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO 'contato' (nome) values ('$nome')");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO 'contato' (email) values ('$email')");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO 'contato' (assunto) values ('$assunto')");
    $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"INSERT INTO 'contato' (mensagem) values ('$mensagem')");
    
    echo "Mensagem enviada obrigado logo estaremos entrando em contato!";
    echo "<input type='button' name='voltar' value='Voltar' href='../index.html'>";
}
?>
```

Sendo que na database eu criei um usuário com esse nome e senha com os privilégios corretos.

Comment: Você consegue realizar a conexão com outro usuário?

Comment: Você também pode utilizando o SGBD de preferência ou pelo terminal mesmo as permissões do usuário. Printe e coloque na sua pergunta. Como fazer? `SHOW GRANTS FOR [USER];`

Comment: Não conheço easyPHP, mas vou arriscar aqui um palpite, caso ele tenha o phpmyadmin acesse ele e vá em contas de usuário, escolha seu usuário criado e vá em editar previlégios, por fim localize essas 3 colunas (Dados
|Estrutura|Administração) e certifique-se de que todas as opções estejam marcadas.

Comment: primeiramente Obrigado a todos que me mandaram as respostas, eu consegui fazer a conexão com a database atraves de um usuario padrão chamado 'root' assim pode concluir e ajustar, agora vou verificar realmente se preciso garantir todos os direitos ao usuario mas isso nao implicaria na segurança da database?

Comment: o codigo ficou da seguinte maneira `include "239839djcie48com.php";` para conectar a db de outro arquivo e `$conexao = mysqli_connect($ip,$conta,$pass,$db);` para conectar creio que isso ajude na segurança